# Datatables not working when loading specific page though id

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatable, sweetalert

i have my page complete with datatables which in this picture [image]

i have a problem once i activate or deactivate my staff the datatables search and sort will be disappeared. i think my error is in the load part. what is the proper way in loading a specific page with div id?

this is the output when activate or deactivate my staff is here[image]

coz what i did is in my base_url+"adminpage/userpage" it is one page for the user and staff. i just did is when i press view staff it will hide the user and will show the staff page which in the same link.

which my code there is here

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#user-page").show();
$("#viewstaff").on("click",function(){
$("#user-page").hide();
$('#staff-page').show();
});
$("#viewuser").on("click",function(){
$("#staff-page").hide();
$("#user-page").show();
});})
```

my code in activate is here

```
function activate_staff(id){

        swal({
  title: 'Are you sure?',
  text: "You want to activate this user?",
  type: 'info',
  showCancelButton: true,
  confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
  cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
  confirmButtonText: 'Yes, Deactivate it!'
}).then(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url : base_url+"adminpage/staff_deactivate/"+id,
        type: "POST",
        success: function(data){
           $('#dataTables-example1').DataTable();

            var result = JSON.parse(data);

            if(result===1){

              swal({
                title: 'Deactivate Success',
                // text: "will remove within 1 sec",
                type: 'success',
                timer: 1500,
                showConfirmButton: false
              }).done()
                window.setTimeout(function(){ 
                 $("#wrapper-staff").load(base_url+"adminpage/useraccount #wrapper-staff > *");

                 } ,1500)
            }
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            swal("Oops...", "Something went wrong :(", "error");
        }
    });
})}
```

and for deactivate is here

```
function deactivate_staff(id){
    swal({
  title: 'Are you sure?',
  text: "You want to deactivate this user?",
  type: 'info',
  showCancelButton: true,
  confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
  cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
  confirmButtonText: 'Yes, Activate it!'
}).then(function() {

    $.ajax({
        url : base_url+"adminpage/staff_activate/"+id,
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        type: "POST",


        success: function(data){

            var result = JSON.parse(data);

            if(result===1){

              swal({
                title: 'Activated Success',
                // text: "will remove within 1 sec",
                type: 'success',
                timer: 1500,
                showConfirmButton: false
              }).done()
                window.setTimeout(function(){


                  $("#wrapper-staff").load(base_url+"adminpage/useraccount #wrapper-staff > *");

                 } ,1500)


            }
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            swal("Oops...", "Something went wrong :(", "error");
        }
    });
})    }
```

Comment: Why load another page ? Why you don't refresh the table ?

Comment: @John im just exploring or let say trying if there is a way that in 1 page i will merge the user and staff. like when i click view staff it will show the staff id and will hide the id of users and vice versa. the problem is the search and pagination of the datatables is gone when i activated or deactivate the staff.

Comment: You are using Datatables library. Then if you load another table without initialize this table with datatables as you did for the first datatable, nothing will work  on the second table. So you have to initialize your second table with Datatables to get all features. But I don't understand why you want load a page inside an element. The refresh table is more appropriate for your case.

Comment: @John in that case. what i must supposed to do on you said refresh table? coz im new to datatables and jquery. just trying to try new things.

Comment: Tell me, when you click on your button activate/desactivate, do you store this value in your database ?

Comment: yes it will update the status in my datatabase.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126328/discussion-between-john-and-edgar-ong).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to change your DataTable to server-side like this [example](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html). After that you can add your buttons on each row like this :

```
table = $('#dataTables-example').DataTable({ 
    "serverSide": true, //Feature control DataTables' server-side processing mode. 

    // Load data for the table's content from an Ajax source 
    "ajax": { 
        "url": "<?php echo site_url('serversidedt/ajax_dt')?>", 
        "type": "POST" 
    }, 

    "columns": [ 
        {data: "fname"}, 
        {data: "lname"}, 
        {data: "email"}, 
        {data: "status"}, 
        {data: myButton, searchable: false, orderable: false} 
    ] 

}); 

function myButton(data, type, dataToSet) { 
    if(dataToSet.status == 1){ 
       return "<button class='btn btn-primary'>Active</button>"; 
    }else{ 
       return "<button class='btn btn-primary'>Desactive</button>"; 
    } 
};
```

And you just have to refresh your DataTable like this :

```
table.ajax.reload( null, false )
```

Hope it help.